# Relationship/Node Charts/Graphs... Using Javascript or something else?

Tags: javascript, charts

Just wondering if any know if there is any JavaScript API out there that allow you to simply plot relationships between nodes.

I would like it if it used JavaScript: 
Something similar to (which doesn't quite work)

> http://ajaxian.com/archives/new-javascriptcanvas-graph-library

Or this (which is nicer but doesn't have any of the layout algorithms)

> http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html

Or if there is an approach like Google charts that can do something similar

I know I can get server side solutions that will do this but I am hopeful for a JS solution.

Cheers
Anthony

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at this, it seems quite elegant.

It's just a bunch of unordered lists and CSS, easy to spit out from JavaScript.

http://astuteo.com/slickmap/

[alt text http://astuteo.com/slickmap/images/slickmap-css-sitemap.png](http://astuteo.com/slickmap/images/slickmap-css-sitemap.png)

Answer (score 6):

I really like MxGraph

http://www.mxgraph.com/demo.html

Comment: Update: mxGraph moved to JGraph (http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html), and it's commercial.